# (JAVA) BMI calc, terminating suddenly

Tags: java

I need to create a BMI program that tells whether you're overweight, underweight, normal or obese. I have no errors, but it starts and automatically terminates. Nothing happens. Debugged and got this.

```
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code     = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [util.c:840]
```

Here is the code.

```
package set2scanner;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ten {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] size = {"Under", "Normal", "Over", "Obese"};

        for (int x = 0; x > 3; x++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your height!");
            float h = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter your weight!");
            float w = input.nextInt();
            float bmi = doMath(h, w);

            if (bmi < 18.5) {
                System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + doMath(h, w) + ". You are " + size[0]);
            } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25.0) {
                System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + doMath(h, w) + ". You are " + size[1]);
            } else if (bmi >= 25.0 && bmi < 30.0) {
                System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + doMath(h, w) + ". You are " + size[2]);
            } else if (bmi >= 30.0) {
                System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + doMath(h, w) + ". You are " + size[3]);
            }
        }    
        input.close();
    }

    static float doMath(float weight, float height) {
        return weight / (height * height);
    }

}
```

Comment: `while x > 3`, but how can that be `true` when `x == 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop you have `int x = 0; x > 3; x++`. Since you initialize `x` on 0, the condition `x > 3` will always be false, thus the loop will never be executed and the program will terminate when you start it

Comment: wow I feel dumb for not catching that. Long day! Thanks haha I was so sure I'd done everything right!

Comment: @JacobKenyon i just noticed something else: when you call `doMath()`, you do `doMath(h, w);` while `doMath()` has the parameters the othwer way around for height and weight

Comment: thanks alot! I messed up a few things but after I fixed the loop I managed to go back and fix all my errors! I had called ints when I was looking for floats instead as well.